# How do I create the letter P in c

Tags: c, drawing

I'm having kinda of trouble. The code I wrote down below it's letter A, and i don't know how to cut on right side to get it to look like letter P. I know this is simple to some of you, but please I really need this help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
int rows,position,i,j;
do{
  printf("insert rows, it must be odd number:");
  scanf("%d",&rows);
}while(rows%2==0);
printf("Insert number of positions, it must be at least half of rows");
scanf("%d",&positions);
for(i=1;i<=rows;i++){
  for(j=1;j<=position;j++){
        if(i==1 || i==(rows/2)+1 || j==1 || j==positions){
printf("/ ");
        }
        else{
           printf("  ");
          }
       }
printf("\n");
}


example:
rows:13
positions:7

now goes print:
///////
/     /
/     /
/     /
/     /
/     /
///////
/     /
/     /
/     /
/     /
/     /
/     /
```

What I need is this

```
///////
/     /
/     /
/     /
/     /
/     /
///////
/     
/     
/     
/     
/     
/
```

Comment: Your code is broken, you're missing a closing `"`.

Comment: That's not C#. Please don't spam language tags.

Comment: There appears to be a missing `"` in the first line in the `while` loop.

Comment: Changing `A` to `P` is easy. Getting your code to compile is the hard part.

Comment: 1) Indent your code properly. 2) Your code does not even compile. Fix it. 3) Create a [mre] and give us expected and actual behavior as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` statement, change:

```
j==positions
```

to:

```
(j==positions && i <= (rows/2)+1)
```

That will block that column after `i` passes `(rows/2)+1`.